# extracting methods and widgets in flutter and problem with their position

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, refactoring

I use method extractions a lot when coding.

[image: extraction method]

it makes the code cleaner, but here's the problem:
visual studio code puts the extracted methods and widgets in bad order, like this:

```
   main(){
     method 1;
     method 2;
     method 3;
   }  
    extracted method 3 {...}
    extracted method 2 {...}
    extracted method 1 {...}
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
    main(){
     method 1;
     method 2;
     method 3;
   } 
    
    extracted method 1 {...}
    extracted method 2 {...}
    extracted method 3 {...}
```

I can't find any option for that. Are there any options for it?

I searched for code options but didn't find any clue, I surfed the internet and Stackoverflow, but that didn't help either.

Comment: 1) https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387964/997587 2) could you try forming your diagrams in textual form? (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541)